# How can I get the lsblk-devices that are NOT in use

Tags: awk, grep, cut, lsblk

```
root@pve-virt-01:~# lsblk
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0   250G  0 disk
├─sda1               8:1    0  1007K  0 part
├─sda2               8:2    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda3               8:3    0 249.5G  0 part
  ├─pve-swap       253:0    0     8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─pve-root       253:1    0  62.3G  0 lvm  /
  ├─pve-data_tmeta 253:2    0   1.6G  0 lvm
  │ └─pve-data     253:4    0   160G  0 lvm
  └─pve-data_tdata 253:3    0   160G  0 lvm
    └─pve-data     253:4    0   160G  0 lvm
sdb                  8:16   0    32G  0 disk
sdc                  8:32   0    32G  0 disk
sdd                  8:48   0    32G  0 disk
sde                  8:64   0    32G  0 disk
```

I just want to see all devices that are not in use for lvm/zfs/ext4 whatever. Do you have something in mind how to archieve this? I want to use it for a script so I can `sgdisk` all unused disk but that means I need to make sure I don't pick a used one.

I want to list all blk devices that are not in use.

Edit:

Output should be:

```
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdc
/dev/sdd
/dev/sde
```

Comment: You want to list all disks that have no partition or lv mounted, in your example `sdb`, `sdc`, `sdd` and `sde`?

Comment: @Philippos yes! But no matter what devices I have, should be usable even on systems that might have nvme0, nvme1 etc.

Comment: This can be easier: `parted -lm /dev/* 2>&1 >/dev/null | awk -F: '{print $2}'`

Comment: Thanks this shows also the mappers

`/dev/sdb
/dev/sdc
/dev/sdd
/dev/sde
/dev/mapper/pve-data
/dev/mapper/pve-data_tdata
/dev/mapper/pve-data_tmeta`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input and clarify in terms of the strings in your input (not general terms like "are not in use" which the strings in your data presumably tell us in some way) why that would be the output.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you want to print devices that themselves and their children have no mountpoints.

Using the JSON output of `lsblk` and `jq`:

```
lsblk --tree -o PATH,MOUNTPOINT -J | jq -r '.blockdevices[]
    | del(select(.mountpoint!=null or .children[]?.mountpoint!=null))
    | .path // empty'
```

Comment: This doesn't work ZFS as their mount points are blank as far as I have seen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you are satisfied with your own script. Here is an `sed` one-liner to parse the plain output of `lsblk`:

```
lsblk | sed -E '/^[a-z]/{x;//s/ .*//p;x;};/^[a-z]|\/|]/h;$!d;x;/^[a-z]/!d;s/ .*//'
```

Short explanation: It stores lines starting with a small letter (the devices) in the hold space, but overwrites them with lines with `/` (mounted) or `]` (swap). If they didn't get overwritten, print them without the trailing stuff of the line.

Scripts like this are easier to write than to read, but I can explain it in detail, if you are interested.

Comment: OP asks for path (`/dev/sdb`) instead of name (`sdb`) output.

Comment: Oh, indeed. I trust OP can add that without help. (-;

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this one but im not sure if Disk Identifier is always set when a disk is in use:

```
for i in $(lsblk -dnp|  awk '{print $1}')
do
    fdisk -l $i| grep 'Disk identifier:'
    if [ $? = '1' ]
    then
        sgdisk -Z $i
        sgdisk -o $i
    fi
done
```

Comment: You should copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net.

Comment: thanks @EdMorton thats a useful tool!

Answer (score 0):

On my system:

```
$ lsblk | awk '$6 == "disk" {if (d) print "/dev/"d; d=$1} {if ($7) d=""} END {if (d) print "/dev/"d}'
/dev/sdv
/dev/sdai
/dev/sdbc
```

Prints any "disk" which doesn't have hanging mount after it.